# Why only able to close one eyelid? Genetic reason?

Tags: genetics

Eye-dominance is a critical thing with bows: right-eye-dominant is recommended to do the aiming on the right eye [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch/?v=aGfI8IqVVfY) otherwise inaccuracy. This made me think whether all people are even able to do this. I have seen people who can only close one eye or two eyes at the same time but not two eyes separately. What is the factor determining this? Is this determined by genes, learning or by something else? Is it possible that the other side of the eye muscles are missing because they have not been needed for the survival? I discussed missing muscles with my medical friends and they mentioned that there are muscles that some people do miss such as in hands because they are not essential for survival. I don't know whether certain muscles in face could be missing with some people or is this just learning thing?

Comment: Without having any scientific knowledge on the matter, I imagine it might simply be a matter of having learned it or not. I remember I had to practice for quite some time as a child before managing to reliably close each eyelid separately.